# Ingest 8-band satellite imagery into an array in C?

Tags: gdal, digital-image-processing, multi-band, c, maxar-digitalglobe

I’ve been unable to locate a lightweight library implemented in C to ingest 8-band geotiff files.  GDAL can do this easily in python, though I’ve been unable to get the GDAL C libraries working; I’ve installed GDAL, but C still can’t find gdal.h.  Do you have any tips as to how to ingest 8-band images with another C library or tips on how to install and set the GDAL paths correctly?